# Object from unknown class, using method in the class

Tags: c#, class, object, methods, delegates

This is my problem: At first, I create a class `cyclicModel` that I want to use its method in main class by delegate. At the `cyclicModel` class, I should use another method, that is defined in monotonic class. I have a lot of monotonic classes `(monotonic1, monotonic2,...)`. The  type of monotonic Class that it should be used is specified by user in main class. How can I invoke the monotonic model that is selected by user at cyclicModel class?!

Comment: does your target language support interfaces/abstract classes? Is the method to be called on monotonicX always the same (has the same signature)?

Comment: Yes, I am working with C# visual studio. The method in each monotonicX has different signature. What should I do know? Can I create an object in main class and then transfer it to cyclicModel class? And If yes, How? Thanks,